# livewire 3 and laravel using select 2 window.livewire.on('data-change-event',()=>{ expression statement is not assignment or call

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, jquery-select2-4

I am trying to use select2 with livewire 3 in laravel 10.
But when I am trying to write a script in resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php, it is showing the below error ,
"()=> expression statement is not assignment or call"

Below is the code that I have used. Any Suggestions on what causing this issue with window.livewire.on('data-change-event'

```
**resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php
**<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.bunny.net">
    <link href="https://fonts.bunny.net/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


    <!-- Scripts -->
    @vite(['resources/sass/app.scss', 'resources/js/app.js'])
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
     

        <main class="py-4">
            @yield('content')
        </main>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // Select2 Multiple
            $('.select2-multiple').select2({
                placeholder: "Select",
                allowClear: true
            });


            window.livewire.on('data-change-event',()=>{

                $('.select2-multiple').select2({
                placeholder: "Select",
                allowClear: true
            });
            });


        });

    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

```
**resources/views/components/layouts/app.blade.php
**

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <title>{{ $title ?? 'Page Title' }}</title>


    </head>
    <body>
        {{ $slot }}
    </body>

</html>
```

```
**resources/views/create-article.blade.php
**
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    @livewire('create-article')

    @endsection

**resources/views/livewire/create-article.blade.php
**
<div>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Create a new article</h1>
        <form wire:submit.prevent="articleFormValidation">

            <div class="mb-3 mt-3">
                <label for="title" class="form-label">Title:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Enter Title" wire:model.live="title">
                @error('title'){{$message}} @enderror

            </div>

            <div class="mb-3 mt-3">
                <label for="description">Description:</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment" name="description"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group mb-3">
                <label for="select2Multiple">Tags</label>
                <select class="select2-multiple form-control" name="tags[]" multiple="multiple"
                        id="select2Multiple">
                    <option value="tag1">tag1</option>
                    <option value="tag2">tag2</option>
                    <option value="tag3">tag3</option>
                </select>
            </div>


            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>

    </div>

</div>
```

```
**CreateArticle.php
**
<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class CreateArticle extends Component
{
    public $title;
    public $description;
    public $tags=[];
    protected $rules=[
        'title'=> 'required',
        'description'=> 'required',

    ];
    public function articleFormValidation()
    {
        $this->validate();
    }
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.create-article');
    }
    public function hydrate()
    {
        $this->emit('data-change-event');
    }
}
```

Comment: my issue is resolved when i used like this  document.addEventListener('livewire:load', function() {

                $('.select2-multiple').select2({
                placeholder: "Select",
                allowClear: true
            });
            });

Comment: then what about this function,
public function hydrate()
{
    $this->emit('data-change-event');
}

still is it used or not?

Answer (score 0):

Still this function

```
public function hydrate()
{
    $this->emit('data-change-event');
}
```

is needed.

Answer (score 0):

$this->emit is depricated now u can use $this->dispatch('data-change-event');

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).